# how to check an ANTLR token is only used once or less in the parser

Tags: parsing, antlr, rules, antlr3

In Antlr, if I have a rule for example:

```
someRule : TOKENA TOKENB;
```

it would accept : "tokena tokenb"

if I would like TOKENA to be optional, I can say,

```
someRule : TOKENA* TOKENB;
```

then I can have : "tokena tokenb" or "tokenb" or "tokena tokena tokenb"

but this also means it can be repeated more that once. Is there anyway I can say this token can be there 1 or less times but not more than one? so it would accept:

"tokena tokenb" or "tokenb" BUT NOT "tokena tokena tokenb"?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... Is there anyway I can say this token can be there 1 or less times but not more than one? ...

Here's how:

```
someRule 
  :  TOKENA? TOKENB
  ;
```

or:

```
someRule 
  :  TOKENA TOKENB
  |  TOKENB
  ;
```

Comment: I understand the second option, I didn't think of being able to do that, my fail. The documentation says the the '?' is a 'semantic predicate' can you explain what a semantic predicate is?

Comment: @Simon, no, `?` by itself means "match the preceding once or none at all".

Comment: @Simon, I was just leaving, but do you want me to post a follow up on what a semantic predicate is? If so, just leave a comment here and I'll post a reply later this evening.

Comment: K, that would be great I was using http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR+Cheat+Sheet but it doesn't really explain what a semantic predicate is, and neither did googling it, so I assumed it was something else...

Comment: @Simon, I posted a separate question (and answer) about semantic predicates here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr