# What is a 'semantic predicate' in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlr4

What is a ***semantic predicate*** in ANTLR?

Comment: Note that since I could not find a decent online resource to post for someone 
who wanted to know what a **semantic predicate** is, I decided to post
the question here myself (which I will shortly answer myself as well).

Comment: Thanks for doing this; I always like it when people answer their own questions, especially if they ask the question specifically to answer it in this way.

Comment: Read the book.  Ch 11 of The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference is on semantic predicates.  Don't have the book?  Get it!  Worth every dollar.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

## ANTLR 4

For predicates in ANTLR 4, checkout these *stack**overflow*** Q&A's:

- [Syntax of semantic predicates in Antlr4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749230/syntax-of-semantic-predicates-in-antlr4)
- [Semantic predicates in ANTLR4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661754/semantic-predicates-in-antlr4)

---

## ANTLR 3

A ***semantic predicate*** is a way to enforce extra (semantic) rules upon grammar 
actions using plain code.

There are 3 types of semantic predicates:

- ***validating*** semantic predicates;
- ***gated*** semantic predicates;
- ***disambiguating*** semantic predicates.

### Example grammar

Let's say you have a block of text consisting of only numbers separated by 
comma's, ignoring any white spaces. You would like to parse this input making 
sure that the numbers are at most 3 digits "long" (at most 999). The following 
grammar (`Numbers.g`) would do such a thing:

```
grammar Numbers;

// entry point of this parser: it parses an input string consisting of at least 
// one number, optionally followed by zero or more comma's and numbers
parse
  :  number (',' number)* EOF
  ;

// matches a number that is between 1 and 3 digits long
number
  :  Digit Digit Digit
  |  Digit Digit
  |  Digit
  ;

// matches a single digit
Digit
  :  '0'..'9'
  ;

// ignore spaces
WhiteSpace
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {skip();}
  ;
```

---

#### Testing

The grammar can be tested with the following class:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("123, 456, 7   , 89");
        NumbersLexer lexer = new NumbersLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        NumbersParser parser = new NumbersParser(tokens);
        parser.parse();
    }
}
```

Test it by generating the lexer and parser, compiling all `.java` files and 
running the `Main` class:

```
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool Numbers.g
javac -cp antlr-3.2.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar Main
```

When doing so, nothing is printed to the console, which indicates that nothing 
went wrong. Try changing:

```
ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("123, 456, 7   , 89");
```

into:

```
ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("123, 456, 7777   , 89");
```

and do the test again: you will see an error appearing on the console right after the string `777`.

---

### Semantic Predicates

This brings us to the semantic predicates. Let's say you want to parse 
numbers between 1 and 10 digits long. A rule like:

```
number
  :  Digit Digit Digit Digit Digit Digit Digit Digit Digit Digit
  |  Digit Digit Digit Digit Digit Digit Digit Digit Digit
     /* ... */
  |  Digit Digit Digit
  |  Digit Digit
  |  Digit
  ;
```

would become cumbersome. Semantic predicates can help simplify this type of rule.

---

#### 1. Validating Semantic Predicates

A *validating semantic predicate* is nothing 
more than a block of code followed by a question mark:

```
RULE { /* a boolean expression in here */ }?
```

To solve the problem above using a ***validating*** 
semantic predicate, change the `number` rule in the grammar into:

```
number
@init { int N = 0; }
  :  (Digit { N++; } )+ { N <= 10 }?
  ;
```

The parts `{ int N = 0; }` and `{ N++; }` are plain Java statements of which 
the first is initialized when the parser "enters" the `number` rule. The actual 
predicate is: `{ N <= 10 }?`, which causes the parser to throw a 
[`FailedPredicateException`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/classorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1_failed_predicate_exception.html) 
whenever a number is more than 10 digits long.

Test it by using the following `ANTLRStringStream`:

```
// all equal or less than 10 digits
ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("1,23,1234567890");
```

which produces no exception, while the following does thow an exception:

```
// '12345678901' is more than 10 digits
ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("1,23,12345678901");
```

---

#### 2. Gated Semantic Predicates

A *gated semantic predicate* is similar to a *validating semantic predicate*, 
only the *gated* version produces a syntax error instead of a `FailedPredicateException`.

The syntax of a *gated semantic predicate* is:

```
{ /* a boolean expression in here */ }?=> RULE
```

To instead solve the above problem using ***gated*** predicates to match numbers up to 10 digits long you would write:

```
number
@init { int N = 1; }
  :  ( { N <= 10 }?=> Digit { N++; } )+
  ;
```

Test it again with both:

```
// all equal or less than 10 digits
ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("1,23,1234567890");
```

and:

```
// '12345678901' is more than 10 digits
ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("1,23,12345678901");
```

and you will see the last on will throw an error.

---

#### 3. Disambiguating Semantic Predicates

The final type of predicate is a *disambiguating semantic predicate*, which looks a bit like  a validating predicate (`{boolean-expression}?`), but acts more like a gated semantic predicate (no exception is thrown when the boolean expression evaluates to `false`). You can use it at the start of a rule to check some property of a rule and let the parser match said rule or not.

Let's say the example grammar creates `Number` tokens (a lexer rule instead of a parser rule) that will match numbers in the range of 0..999. Now in the parser, you'd like to make a distinction between low- and hight numbers (low: 0..500, high: 501..999). This could be done using a *disambiguating semantic predicate* where you inspect the token next in the stream (`input.LT(1)`) to check if it's either low or high.

A demo:

```
grammar Numbers;

parse
  :  atom (',' atom)* EOF
  ;

atom
  :  low  {System.out.println("low  = " + $low.text);}
  |  high {System.out.println("high = " + $high.text);}
  ;

low
  :  {Integer.valueOf(input.LT(1).getText()) <= 500}? Number
  ;

high
  :  Number
  ;

Number
  :  Digit Digit Digit
  |  Digit Digit
  |  Digit
  ;

fragment Digit
  :  '0'..'9'
  ;

WhiteSpace
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {skip();}
  ;
```

If you now parse the string `"123, 999, 456, 700, 89, 0"`, you'd see the following output:

```
low  = 123
high = 999
low  = 456
high = 700
low  = 89
low  = 0
```

Comment: Man you really should consider writing a beginner's guide to ANTLR :P

Comment: For ANTLR v4, `input.LT(1)` is `getCurrentToken()` now :-)

Comment: Fantastic... This is the kind of exhaustive explanation and examples that should be in the docs!

Comment: +1. This answer is far far better than the The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference book. This answer is spot on the concept with nice examples.

Comment: what kind of grammar is allowed inside a semantic predicate?  What's with the $?  Is this javascript?

Comment: @johnktejik when referencing a rule in some custom code (the stuff between `{ ... }`), you must start with a `$`. And inside a predicate (the `{ ... }?` construct) you can put just plain code (whatever language you're targeting).

Comment: I tried to run this and got an error, invalid input

Comment: @johnktejik when using ANTLRv3, I didn't get an error. Perhaps you're using v4?

Answer (score 13):

I've always used the terse reference to [ANTLR predicates](https://wincent.com/wiki/ANTLR_predicates) on wincent.com as my guide.

Comment: Yes, an excellent link! But, as you mention, it might be a bit difficult for someone (relatively) new to ANTLR. I just hope my answer is (a bit) friendlier for the ANTLR-grass-hopper. :)