# How to solve a problem with ANTLR mismatch input

Tags: antlr, antlr3

given the grammar

```
test    : 'test' ID '\n' 'begin' '\n'  'end' '\n' -> ^(TEST ID);

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;
```

and a test string of

```
"test blah\n begin\n end\n"
```

resulting in

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'test blah\\n begin\\n end\\n' expecting 'test'
<mismatched token: [@0,0:21='test blah\\n begin\\n end\\n',<12>,1:0], resync=test blah
 begin
 end
>
```

whats gone wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `'\n'` in your grammar rules, you're not matching a `backslash+n` but a new line character. And it looks like your input does not contain new line characters but `backslash+n`'s.

So, my guess is you need to either change your `test` rule into:

```
test    
  : 'test' ID '\\n' 'begin' '\\n'  'end' '\\n'
  ;
```

resulting in the parse-tree:

[image]

or leave your `test` rule *as is* but change your input into:

```
test blah
begin
end
```

resulting in the parse-tree:

[image]

If that is not the case, could you post a SSCCE: a small, full working demo that I (or someone else can run) that shows this error?

Comment: actually I was completely NOOB,  I had some other tokens defined and one of them was matching.  So I guess in the lexer it was tokenizing it, which then meant when it was parsing it would see the wrong token ( even though it could parse the characters )

Comment: and seriously, you should write a C# tutorial, your answers on here about antlr and C# have been a great...no.....AWESOME help!

Comment: @Keith, yeah, I commented about the ANTLR & C# tutorial before to you (which I removed since I made a bit of a vague suggestion in that same comment...). It's still my planning to do so. When I do, I will post it here on SO as a Q&A like I did with my (short) [explanation on ANTLR's semantic predicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr).