# ANTLR3: Parameters and semantic predicates ("cannot find symbol", "illegal start of type")

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I would like to realize a "branch" in ANTLR3.

I figured using

```
branch[boolean is_a]
    : ({ $is_a}? => a)
    | ({!$is_a}? => b);
```

would do the trick, but I get the compiling errors "cannot find symbol" and "illegal start of type", because in the in the generated source i.e. `DFA45.specialStateTransition(...)` does not have a parameter `is_a`.

I tried omitting the `=>`¹, and/or omitting the `$` of `$is_a`.

The FIRST sets of `a` and `b` are not disjoint.

In fact `b` is of type `((C) => c) | a`.

¹) as I don't understand the difference between `{...}? => ...` and `{...}? ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why you get that error: I'd need to see your entire grammar for that. Anyway, there is no need to check for both `is_a` *and* `!is_a`. And both `$is_a` and `is_a` are valid.

Let's say you're parsing a list of numbers, and every 4th number, you want to handle through a different "branch". A grammar for that would look like:

```
grammar T;

parse
@init{int n = 1;}
  :  (number[n\%4 == 0] {n++;})+ EOF
  ;


number [boolean multipleOf4]
  :  {multipleOf4}?=> Int {System.out.println("branch A -> " + $Int.text);}
  |                   Int {System.out.println("branch B :: " + $Int.text);}
  ;

Int
  :  '0'..'9'+
  ;

Space
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {skip();}
  ;
```

*(note that the `%` is a reserved character inside ANTLR grammars (not inside String literals and comments though), so it needs escaping with a backslash)*

And can be tested with the class:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99");
        TLexer lexer = new TLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);
        parser.parse();
    }
}
```

Now generate a parser/lexer (A), compile all source files (B) and run the main class (C):

```
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool T.g // A
javac -cp antlr-3.2.jar *.java            // B
java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar Main             // C
```

*(on Windows, run it by doing `java -cp .;antlr-3.2.jar Main`)*

which produces the following output:

```
branch B :: 11
branch B :: 22
branch B :: 33
branch A -> 44
branch B :: 55
branch B :: 66
branch B :: 77
branch A -> 88
branch B :: 99
```

So, yes, you needed a *"gated semantic predicate"* (`{boolean}?=>`) in this case, not a *"validating semantic predicate"* (`{boolean}?`). The difference between the two predicates is explained in this previous SO Q&A: [What is a 'semantic predicate' in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr)

Comment: @Kay, if you want, you could post the grammar you're working on and I'll have a look later on. Perhaps you can't post it in its entire form (work), but in that case, I won't be able to help (nor can someone else, is my guess).

Comment: It seems the language has to be "difficult enough" to render the problem. The generated code contains a `alt45 = dfa45.predict(input);` line in the `branch(boolean is_a)` method. DFA45.predict in turn uses is_a to predicate the next branch, but the variable is not passed along. Now I use `b {if(!is_b) throw new FailedPredicateException(...);}` which works fine for me. Thank you for the "What is a 'semantic predicate' in ANTLR" link!