# Can this grammar be parsed using antlr4?

Tags: antlr4

Given a set *S* of *n* rules, I need an antlr4 rule to match any of *S* subset, in any order :

- each rule of *S* can appear zero or one time
- any permutation of the subset is ok

**Example** :

Given *S* = {a,b}, (*n* = 2) the rule must match

- a
- b
- a b
- b a

while "a b b", for instance must not match.

It is possible to parse such expression with an antlr4 grammar ? My real set has *n* = 6, so listing all combinations in the grammar seems not to be a possible choice !

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself?

Comment: @ScottHunter Sure I did. I Think it is not possible, in fact, but I could have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't define combinations and/or permutations of rules in ANTLR (or any other parser generator that I know).

You could use [predicates to accomplish your goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883992/in-antlr-is-there-a-shortcut-notation-for-expressing-alternation-of-all-the-per), but that means adding target specific code to your grammar: I'd just parse any `a` or `b` and validate the structure after parsing (in a custom visitor/listener).

Comment: Given link gives the perfect antlr4/java code for this problem.

Comment: Note that the link is for ANTLR3, but ANTLR4 doesn't differ much w.r.t. predicates and embedded code.