# antlr4: how to choose at most one of each token from a token set in a parser rule

Tags: antlr4

I'm creating an antlr4 grammar for a language that has several possibilities for variable declaration prefixes, e.g. a variable declaration could be any of the following:

```
IDENTIFIER
PREFIX1 IDENTIFIER
PREFIX2 IDENTIFIER
PREFIX1 PREFIX2 IDENTIFIER
PREFIX2 PREFIX1 IDENTIFIER
```

and the prefixes are optional and can be in any order, but at most one of each.

If I have a rule:

```
var_declaration: (PREFIX1 | PREFIX2)? IDENTIFIER;
```

then that will handle none or a single prefix of either type.  How do I handle none, one or both in either order but prevent two prefixes the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special syntax for that. You will have a define all alternatives:

```
var_declaration
 : PREFIX1 PREFIX2 IDENTIFIER
 | PREFIX2? PREFIX1? IDENTIFIER
 ;
```

If there are more than 2 prefixes, listing them will become verbose. In that case, it's best to match any of them zero or more times:

```
var_declaration
 : prefix* IDENTIFIER
 ;

prefix
 : PREFIX1
 | PREFIX2
 | PREFIX3
 ;
```

and then checking after the parse (using a tree-listener) if the prefixes that got matched are unique.

Related Q&A: [In ANTLR, is there a shortcut notation for expressing alternation of all the permutations of some set of rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883992/in-antlr-is-there-a-shortcut-notation-for-expressing-alternation-of-all-the-per)