# ANTLR: how to parse a region within matching brackets with a lexer

Tags: antlr, matching, lexer, brackets

i want to parse something like this in my lexer:

```
( begin expression )
```

where expressions are also surrounded by brackets. it isn't important what is in the expression, i just want to have all what's between the `(begin` and the matching `)` as a token. an example would be:

```
(begin 
    (define x (+ 1 2)))
```

so the text of the token should be

```
(define x (+ 1 2)))
```

something like

```
PROGRAM : LPAREN BEGIN .* RPAREN;
```

does (obviously) not work because as soon as he sees a ")", he thinks the  rule is over, but i need the matching bracket for this.

how can i do that?

Comment: If you want to recognize everything between (...) including other nested (...), then you can't do it with a pure, standard regexp based lexer (such as ANTLR has, I think), because regexes can't count --> can't determine when the parentheses are balanced. You need to implement a lexeme recognizers that can count parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside lexer rules, you can invoke rules recursively. So, that's one way to solve this. Another approach would be to keep track of the number of open- and close parenthesis and let a [*gated semantic predicate*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr)  loop as long as your counter is more than zero.

### A demo:

### T.g

```java
grammar T;

parse
  :  BeginToken {System.out.println("parsed :: " + $BeginToken.text);} EOF
  ;

BeginToken 
@init{int open = 1;}
  :  '(' 'begin' ( {open > 0}?=>              // keep reapeating `( ... )*` as long as open > 0
                     ( ~('(' | ')')           // match anything other than parenthesis
                     | '('          {open++;} // match a '(' in increase the var `open`
                     | ')'          {open--;} // match a ')' in decrease the var `open`
                     )
                 )*
  ;
```

### Main.java

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "(begin (define x (+ (- 1 3) 2)))";
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(input));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

```
java -cp antlr-3.3-complete.jar org.antlr.Tool T.g
javac -cp antlr-3.3-complete.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3-complete.jar Main

parsed :: (begin (define x (+ (- 1 3) 2)))
```

Note that you'll need to beware of string literals inside your  source that might include parenthesis:

```java
BeginToken
@init{int open = 1;}
  :  '(' 'begin' ( {open > 0}?=>              // ...
                     ( ~('(' | ')' | '"')     // ...
                     | '('          {open++;} // ...
                     | ')'          {open--;} // ...
                     |  '"' ...               // TODO: define a string literal here
                     )
                 )*
  ;
```

or comments that may contain parenthesis.

The suggestion with the predicate uses some language specific code (Java, in this case). An advantage of calling a lexer rule recursively is that you don't have custom code in your lexer:

```java
BeginToken 
  :  '(' Spaces? 'begin' Spaces? NestedParens Spaces? ')'
  ;

fragment NestedParens
  :  '(' ( ~('(' | ')') | NestedParens )* ')'
  ;

fragment Spaces
  :  (' ' | '\t')+
  ;
```

Comment: @Ira, it _is_ a single lexeme. Rules that start with an uppercase are tokens in ANTLR. My naming the rule `Root` was perhaps a poor choice, which lead you to believe I pushed the problem to the parser...

Comment: Aha. Yeah, as you might guess, I'm not exactly an ANTLR expert.  So ...this is the answer I expected you would provide.  I'll never doubt you again!

Comment: @Bart: i just noticed another problem i have with this: the lexer won't recognize statements like `(bar ...)` correctly anymore, instead he throws away the '(ba' and just returns the `r` as an identifier altough i want to have LPAREN IDENTIFIER. how can i fix this? should i open another question for that and post the grammar again?

Comment: Yeah, that's something the lexer doesn't like. In case of input that "looks" like `(b...`, the lexer has problems backing up to `LPAREN IDENTIFIER` instead of `BeginToken`. Is it really something you want to handle in your lexer? It'd be easier to match a `beginToken` in the parser than a `BeginToken` in the lexer. And yeah, it'd probably be easier to create a new question (in case you really want to do this in the lexer).