# Writing Bison grammar to recognise JavaScript functions and ignore everything else

Tags: javascript, parsing, yacc, context-free-grammar, jison

I am trying to:

1. Read my JavaScript code through my grammar
2. Write a particular line inside the body of each function.

For example,

Input

```
function(){
    console.log('this is some function');
}
function somefunc (args){
    console.log('this is some other function');
    function(){
         console.log('function inside a function');
    }
}
```

Output

```
    function(){
        //auto generated debug log
        debug('some text');
        console.log('this is some function');
    }
    function somefunc (args){
       //auto generated debug log
       debug('some text');
       console.log('this is some other function');
       function(){
          //auto generated debug log
          debug('some text');
          console.log('function inside a function');
      }
   }
```

I am able to recognize the function, but I am not able to put everything in a single piece. I need some breadcrumbs to move in the correct direction of writing grammar to achieve the desired output.

Is my idea to just concentrate on parsing function and ignoring everything else (i.e., dumping them back) inherently flawed?

So far, I have done:

```
/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
"("                   return '('
")"                   return ')'
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF'
"function"          return 'FUNCTION'
"{"              return '{'
"}"              return '}'
.              return 'ANYTHING'
/lex

/* operator associations and precedence */


%start expr

%% /* language grammar */

expr: any EOF
      {typeof console !== 'undefined' ? console.log($1) : print($1);
          return $1;}
;
fun: FUNCTION '(' any ')' '{' any '}'
     {$$=$1+$2+$3+$4+$5+'console.log(something)'+$6+$7}
;

any: ANYTHING
     {$$=$1;}
   | any ANYTHING
      {$$=$1+$2}
   |  FUNCTION '(' any ')' '{' any '}'
     {$$=$1+$2+$3+$4+$5+'console.log(something)'+$6+$7}
;
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is my idea to just concentrate on parsing function and ignoring everything else (i.e. dumping them back) inherently flawed?

It's not inherently flawed. In fact, it is a common approach [Note 1]. However, your solution requires more work.

First, you need to make your lexer more robust. It should correctly identify comments and string literals. Otherwise, you risk matching false positives: apparent tokens hidden in such literals. Ideally you would also identify regexes but that is a lot more complicated since it requires cooperation from the parser, and a simplistic parser such as the one which you propose does not have enough context to distinguish division operators from the start of a regular expression. [Note 2]

You also need to recognize identifiers; otherwise, an identifier which happened to contain the characters `function` (such as `compare_function`) would also be a false match.

The problem arises because `any` cannot contain a `FUNCTION` token. So if your scanner produces a stray `FUNCTION` token, the parse will fail.

Also, remember that parentheses and braces are not `ANYTHING` tokens. Since a program will typically have many parentheses and braces which are not part of a function literal, you will need to add these to your `any` rules. Note that you don't want to add them as single tokens; rather, you need to add parenthesis-balanced sequences (`'(' any ')'`, for example). Otherwise, you will have a shift-reduce conflict on the `'}'`. (`function(){ var a = { };...`: how does the parser know that the `}` does not close the function body?)

It will probably prove simpler to have two non-terminals, something like this [Note 3]:

```
any: /* empty */    { $$ = ""; }
   | any any_object { $$ = $1 + $2; }
   ;
any_object
   : ANYTHING
   | fun
   | '(' any ')'    { $$ = $1 + $2 + $3; }
   | '{' any '}'    { $$ = $1 + $2 + $3; }
   ;
```

The other issue you have is that whitespace is skipped by your scanner, so your parser will never see it. That means it won't be present in the semantic values so it will be stripped by your transformation. That will break any program which depends on automatic semicolon insertion, as well as certain other constructs (`return 42;`, for example; `return42;` is quite different.) You will probably want to recognize whitespace as a separate token, and add it both to your `any` rules (or the `any_object` rule above), as well as an optional element in  your `fun` rule between `function` and `(` and between `)` and `{`. (Since whitespace will be included in `any`, you must not add it beside an `any` non-terminal; that could cause a reduce-reduce conflict.)

Speaking of automatic semicolon insertion, you would be well-advised not to rely on it in your transformed program. You should put an explicit semicolon after the inserted `console.log(...)` statement.

---

#### Notes

1. As Ira Baxter points out in a comment, this approach is generally called an "island parser", from the idea that you are trying to find "islands" in an ocean of otherwise uninteresting text. A useful paper which I believe popularized this term is Leon Moonen's 2001 contribution to WCRE, "Generating robust parsers using island grammars". (Google will find you full-text PDFs.) Google will also find you other information about this paradigm, including Ira Baxter's own more pessimistic answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7205784/1566221)
2. This is probably the most serious objection to the basic idea. If you don't want to address it, you'll need to place the following restrictions on regular expressions in the programs you want to transform:

   - parentheses and braces must be balanced
   - the regular expression cannot contain the string `function`.

   The second restriction is relatively simple, since you could replace `function` with the entirely equivalent `[f]unction`. The first one is more troublesome; you would need to replace `/(/` with something like `/\x28/`.
3. In your proposed grammar, there is an error because of a confusion about what `any` represents. The third production for `any` should not  be a duplicate of the `fun` production; instead, it should allow `fun` to be added to an `any` sequence. (Perhaps you just left out `any` from that production. But even so, there is no need to repeat the `fun` production when you can just use the non-terminal.)

Comment: Love your answers.  You might note the term for this is "island parser", where the "island" is the text you want to keep, and the "water" is stuff you want to ignore.

Comment: @IraBaxter: Yes, that's worth mentioning for its googlability. I added it with a footnote.

Comment: thanks for such an elaborate response. I have been trying my whole weekend to fill the holes in my grammar (especially the space issue). It seems i should start afresh after revisiting the necessary concepts.