# ANTLR Matching all tokens except

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Is there any way to match a token in antlr except a specific one?

I have a rule which states that a `'_'` can be an ID. Now I have a specific situation in which I want to match an ID, but in this particular case I want it to ignore the `'_'` alternative. Is it possible?

Comment: I browsed through your questions a bit and many of them seem to have decent answers, yet most of them are not accepted. You _do_ seem to favor your own answers you provide to your questions... :)

Comment: @halfwarp Does the answer qualify as acceptable? If yes please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like

```
(ID {!$ID.text.equals("_")}?)
```

should do it (if you are using Java as target language). Otherwise you will have to write that [semantic predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr) in a way that your language understands it.

In short, this will check whether the text does not equal "_" and only then will the subrule match.

Another possible way to do this:

```
id: ID
  | '_'
  ;

ID: // lexer rule to match every valid identifier EXCEPT '_' ;
```

That way, whenever you mean "either '_' or any other ID", you use `id` to match this, if you disallow "_", you can use `_`.