# Parsing a templating language

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to parse a templating language and I'm having trouble correctly parsing the arbitrary html that can appear between tags. So far what I have is below, any suggestions? An example of a valid input would be

```
{foo}{#bar}blah blah blah{zed}{/bar}{>foo2}{#bar2}This Should Be Parsed as a Buffer.{/bar2}
```

And the grammar is:

```
grammar g;

options {
  language=Java;
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

/* LEXER RULES */
tokens {

}

LD  :    '{';
RD  :    '}';
LOOP    :    '#';  
END_LOOP:   '/';
PARTIAL :   '>';
fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9';
fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
IDENT : (LETTER | '_') (LETTER | '_' | DIGIT)*;
BUFFER options {greedy=false;} : ~(LD | RD)+ ;

/* PARSER RULES */
start   : body EOF
;

body    : (tag | loop | partial | BUFFER)*
;

tag     : LD! IDENT^ RD!
;

loop    : LD! LOOP^ IDENT RD!
  body
  LD! END_LOOP! IDENT RD!
;

 partial : LD! PARTIAL^ IDENT RD!
;

buffer  : BUFFER 
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lexer tokenizes independently from your parser. If your parser tries to match a `BUFFER` token, the lexer does not take this info into account. In your case with input like: `"blah blah blah"`, the lexer creates 3 `IDENT` tokens, not a single `BUFFER` token.

What you need to "tell" your lexer is that when you're inside a tag (i.e. you encountered a `LD` tag), a `IDENT` token should be created, and when you're outside a tag (i.e. you encountered a `RD` tag), a `BUFFER` token should be created instead of an `IDENT` token.

In order to implement this, you need to:

1. create a `boolean` flag inside the lexer that keeps track of the fact that you're in- or outside a tag. This can be done inside the `@lexer::members { ... }` section of your grammar;
2. after the lexer either creates a `LD`- or `RD`-token, flip the `boolean` flag from (1). This can be done in the `@after{ ... }` section of the lexer rules;
3. before creating a `BUFFER` token inside the lexer, check if you're outside a tag at the moment. This can be done by using a *[semantic predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr)* at the start of your lexer rule.

A short demo:

```java
grammar g;

options { 
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree; 
}

@lexer::members {
  private boolean insideTag = false;
}

start   
  :  body EOF -> body
  ;

body
  :  (tag | loop | partial | BUFFER)*
  ;

tag
  :  LD IDENT RD -> IDENT
  ;

loop    
  :  LD LOOP IDENT RD body LD END_LOOP IDENT RD -> ^(LOOP body IDENT IDENT)
  ;

partial 
  :  LD PARTIAL IDENT RD -> ^(PARTIAL IDENT)
  ;

LD @after{insideTag=true;}  : '{';
RD @after{insideTag=false;} : '}';

LOOP     : '#';  
END_LOOP : '/';
PARTIAL  : '>';
SPACE    : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
IDENT    :  (LETTER | '_') (LETTER | '_' | DIGIT)*;
BUFFER   : {!insideTag}?=> ~(LD | RD)+;

fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9';
fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
```

*(note that you probably want to discard spaces between tag, so I added a `SPACE` rule and discarded these spaces)*

Test it with the following class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String src = "{foo}{#bar}blah blah blah{zed}{/bar}{>foo2}{#bar2}" + 
                 "This Should Be Parsed as a Buffer.{/bar2}";
    gLexer lexer = new gLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(src));
    gParser parser = new gParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.start().getTree();
    DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
    StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
    System.out.println(st);
  }
}
```

and after running the main class:

### *nix/MacOS

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool g.g 
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main
```

### Windows

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool g.g 
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .;antlr-3.3.jar Main
```

You'll see some DOT-source being printed to the console, which corresponds to the following AST:

[image]

*(image created using [graphviz-dev.appspot.com](http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com))*