# Switching lexer state in antlr3 grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to construct an antlr grammar to parse a templating language. that language can be embedded in any text and the boundaries are marked with opening/closing tags: `{{` / `}}`. So a valid template looks like this:

```
    foo {{ someVariable }} bar
```

Where `foo` and `bar` should be ignored, and the part inside the `{{` and `}}` tags should be parsed. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381063/parsing-a-templating-language) which basically has an answer for the problem, except that the tags are only one `{` and `}`. I've tried to modify the grammar to match 2 opening/closing characters, but as soon as i do this, the `BUFFER` rule consumes ALL characters, also the opening and closing brackets. The `LD` rule is never being invoked.

Has anyone an idea why the antlr lexer is consuming all tokens in the `Buffer` rule when the delimiters have 2 characters, but does not consume the delimiters when they have only one character?

```
    grammar Test;

    options { 
      output=AST;
      ASTLabelType=CommonTree; 
    }

    @lexer::members {
      private boolean insideTag = false;
    }

    start   
      :  (tag | BUFFER )*
      ;

    tag
      : LD IDENT^ RD
      ;

    LD @after {
      // flip lexer the state
      insideTag=true;
      System.err.println("FLIPPING TAG");
    } : '{{';

    RD @after {
      // flip the state back
      insideTag=false;
    } : '}}';

    SPACE    : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
    IDENT    : (LETTER)*;
    BUFFER   : { !insideTag }?=> ~(LD | RD)+;

    fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
```

Comment: Beware that `IDENT : (LETTER)*;` (might) cause the lexer to go in an infinite loop. Lexer rule _must_ always match at least 1 character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match any character once or more until you see `{{` ahead by including a predicate inside the parenthesis `( ... )+` (see the `BUFFER` rule in the demo).

A demo:

```
grammar Test;

options { 
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree; 
}

@lexer::members {
  private boolean insideTag = false;
}

start   
  :  tag EOF
  ;

tag
  : LD IDENT^ RD
  ;

LD 
@after {insideTag=true;} 
 : '{{'
 ;

RD 
@after {insideTag=false;} 
 : '}}'
 ;

BUFFER
 : ({!insideTag && !(input.LA(1)=='{' && input.LA(2)=='{')}?=> .)+ {$channel=HIDDEN;}
 ;

SPACE 
 : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
 ;

IDENT
 : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
 ;
```

Note that it's best to keep the `BUFFER` rule as the first lexer rule in your grammar: that way, it will be the first token that is tried.

If you now parse `"foo {{ someVariable }} bar"`, the following AST is created:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a grammar like this fit your needs? I don't see why the BUFFER needs to be that complicated.

```
grammar test;

options { 
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree; 
}

@lexer::members { 
    private boolean inTag=false;
}

start   
  :  tag* EOF
  ;

tag
  : LD IDENT RD -> IDENT
  ;

LD 
@after { inTag=true; }
 : '{{'
 ;

RD 
@after { inTag=false; }
 : '}}'
 ;

IDENT   :   {inTag}?=> ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') 'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

BUFFER
 : . {$channel=HIDDEN;}
 ;
```