# Lexer tokenises unexpectedly

Tags: antlr, antlr3, lexer

The following extremely simple example grammar doesn't lex as I expected (at all).

```
Declaration :   'VAR';
Letter: ('A'..'Z');

message :   Declaration Letter+;
```

what I expected as a result is that any sequence of letters would lex as individual letters, and the sequence 'VAR' would be lexed as a single token.

When I look at the ANTLRWorks interperter I see the following results:

- `VARA` parses into `message -> "VAR", "A"` (expected)
- `VARVA` doesn't parse (MismatchedTokenException(-1 != 5). The lexer hits the second `VA` and tries to tokenise `Declaration`. Expected: `message -> "VAR", "V", "A"`
- `VARVPP` parses into `message -> "VAR", "V", "P", "P"` (expected)
- `VARVALL` parses into `message -> "VAR", "VALL"`.

I would like some help understanding this behaviour, and a suggestion how I can fix this.

Specifically:

- Why does the lexer try to tokenise all strings starting with `VA` into Declaration if it is followed by one letter?
- Why doesn't the lexer try to do this with all strings starting with a `V`?
- Why doesn't the lexer try to do this if there is an additional character there?
- How should I change this grammar to parse the way I expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's go through all of your 4 examples:

### 1 "VARA"

[image]

All okay.

### 2 "VARVA"

`"VAR"` is (obviously) tokenized as `VAR`, but then the lexer "sees" `"VA"` and expects an `"R"`, which is not there. It emits the following errors:

```
line 1:5 mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting 'R'
line 1:5 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input '<EOF>'
```

and discards the `"VA"` resulting in a single token to be created, as you can see when running ANTLRWorks' debugger (ignore the exceptions in the parse, they're not actually there :)):

[image]

The thing you must realize is that the lexer will *never* give up on something it has already matched. So if the lexer *sees* `"VA"` and cannot match an `"R"` after it, it will then look at the other lexer rules that can match `"VA"`. But `Letter` does not match that (it only matches single letters!) If you change `Letter` to match more than a single character, ANTLR would be able to fall back on that rule. But not when it matches a single letter: the lexer will not give up the `"A"` from `"VA"` to let the `Letter` rule match. No way around it: this is how ANTLR's lexer works.

This is usually not an issue because there is often some sort of `IDENTIFIER` rule that the lexer can fall back on when a keyword cannot be matched.

### 3 "VARVPP"

[image]

All okay: `"VAR"` becomes a `VAR` and then the lexer tries to match an `"A"` after the `"V"` but this does not happen, so the lexer falls back on the `Letter` rule for the single `"V"`. After that `"PP"` are both tokenized as `Letter`s.

### 4 "VARVALL"

`"VAR"` again becomes a `VAR`. Then the `"L"` in `"VAL"` causes the lexer to produce the following error message:

```
line 1:5 mismatched character 'L' expecting 'R'
```

and then the last `"L"` becomes a `Letter`:

[image]

---

I guess (or hope) the first 3 question are now answered, which leaves your final answer:

> How should I change this grammar to parse the way I expected?

By forcing the lexer to first look ahead in the character stream if there really is `"VAR"` ahead, and if there's not, just match a single `"V"` and change the type of the matched token to `Letter`, like this:

```
Declaration
 : ('VAR')=> 'VAR'
 |           'V'   {$type=Letter;}
 ;
```

As mentioned before my answer, see this related Q&A: [ANTLR lexer can't lookahead at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190501/antlr-lexer-cant-lookahead-at-all)

Answer (score 2):

The lexer doesn't really perform lookahead, only the parser does; you can read more about it in [ANTLR lexer can't lookahead at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190501/antlr-lexer-cant-lookahead-at-all). So the problem here is that, once the lexer fails to match `VAR`, it tries to match what it got so far - `VA` - and there's no matching token, since Letter cannot match two characters, just one.

As for a solution, a trivial one is to change it to be a single token:

```
Message :   'VAR' ('A'..'Z')+;
message :   Message;
```

It won't net you a different token for each letter, though.

Comment: Ah, I now see what you mean. Yes, you are correct: your suggestion will indeed work for the 4 examples the OP posted. But my guess it that the OP's *real* question is how to make it so that input like `"VA"` followed by something other than `"R"` is tokenized as `Letter`s instead of a (failed) `VAR` token. Again, sorry for all the confusion.