# How to deal with Xtext lexer if it doesn't backtrack and how to disable tokens highlighting?

Tags: antlr3, xtext, lexer, backtracking

I have a grammar of RQL adapted for my work and it differs from the Oracle grammar. The main difference is that string literals are not surrounded by double quotes.

```
Model:
    operands+=HoOperand ( (','|'&') HoOperand )*
;

And: '&' HoOperand;
Or: (';'|'|') HoOperand;

HoOperand:
    WSP* ( HigherOrderCall | Comparison ) WSP*
;

HigherOrderCall:
    LogicalOpAliases WSP* '(' ( HoOperand ( ',' HoOperand )* ) ')'
;

CompOps : ('!='|'='|'<'|'<='|'>'|'>=');
Comparison : Strval WSP* ( CompOps ) Strval;

Nchar: (ALPHA|DIGIT|'-'|'.'|'_'|'~'|'$'|':'|'*'|'+'|'?'|'/'|'@');
Pct_encoded: '%' XDIGIT XDIGIT;    
Strval:    (Nchar|Pct_encoded)+;
LogicalOpAliases: ('or'|'and'|'not');

terminal DIGIT:    ('0'..'9');
terminal XDIGIT: (DIGIT|'A'..'F');        
terminal ALPHA:    ('A'..'Z'|'a'..'z');
terminal WSP: (' '|'\t');
```

I've encountered such a problem: because of the difference noticed earlier entries like `or=a` and `or(a=a)` match the different rules, the first matches `Comparison` and the second matches `HigherOrderCall`. Accordingly to this the first `or` matches `Strval` and the second matches `LogicalOpAliases` in those rules they are the different terminals and I need lexer to backtrack.

I've already read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190501/antlr-lexer-cant-lookahead-at-all) and the answer to it. I tried to include `LogicalOpAliases` in `Strval`, it solved this issue partially (entries like `anf=a` are considered to be mistaken because of the lexer greediness, it tries to consume `and` and doesn't backtrack).

How can I resolve this problem?

And the second question is about highlighting. In the entry `or=` where `or` matches string literal `or` is  highlighted. I tried to make rule `LogicalOpAliases` terminal rule, but highlighting disappeared at all. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you have to fix your grammar.

Xtext grammars are not just parser specifications, but they are also used to infer the classes for the AST. You have to use [assigned actions](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html#grammar-actions) in the appropiate places, and be aware of the implications of direct rule calls like `And: '&' HoOperand;` to the inferred class hierarchy (the way the grammar is written, `HoOperand` would be a subclass of both `And` and `Or`).

Also, it would make sense to reduce clutter by defining `WSP` as a hidden token using `hidden(WSP)` instead of including it in every place where whitespace is allowed.