# Optimal ambiguity resolving

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3, ambiguity

I am trying to resolve how to handle ambiguities in `ANTLR`. 
I need to parse identifiers or identifiers with size prefix correctly.
First I came up to this buggy grammar

```
grammar PrefixProblem;
options       
{   
    language = Java;
}
goal: (size_prefix ':')? id;
size_prefix: B;
id: LETTER+;
LETTER: 'A'..'Z' ;
B: 'B';
WSFULL:(' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

I need to handle `B` as `ID`, `B:B` as `id` `B` with prefix `B`. It didn't work.

Then I found two solutions to this problem.

```
grammar PrefixSolution1;
options       
{   
    language = Java;
}
goal: (size_prefix ':')? id;
size_prefix: B;
id: (LETTER | B)+;
LETTER: 'A' | 'C'..'Z' ;
B: 'B';
WSFULL:(' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

In the code above `B` was removed from a `lexer` rule and concatenated in `id` rule.

```
grammar PrefixSolution2;
options       
{   
    language = Java;
}
goal: PREFIX_VAR;
PREFIX_VAR: (B WSFULL* ':' WSFULL*)? ID;
fragment ID: (LETTER)+;
fragment LETTER: 'A'..'Z' ;
fragment B: 'B';
WSFULL:(' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

Here I just moved a rule to the `lexer`.

`PrefixSolution1` has the main con that I need to stripe lexer rules into smaller chunks and then concatecate later.

`PrefixSolution2`: this approach leads that i need always to take an account white space characters which should be ignored.

As for me both solutions will lead to a big mess writing a grammar for a whole language. Is there any other solution? If not, which way is the most optimal one?

All source code is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mf42x6rpzzho2ra/OfG33UJzWt/ANTLRProblem/Prefix)

Comment: Ok so you will need something like this: "B" and something like this: "B:B", and in AST when "B" occurs you need to identify it as ID and when "B:B" occurs you need to identify it as ID with Prefix? Did I got it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go with either of them. I'd simply create `ID` tokens and *not* `B` tokens (or create `PREFIX_VAR` tokens: this belongs in the parser).

You can match a capital B (`capB`) using a *disambiguating semantic predicate*<sup>1</sup> in a parser rule like this:

```
grammar Test;

goal
 : (prefixVar | ID)+ EOF
 ;

prefixVar
 : capB ':' ID 
 ;

capB
 : {input.LT(1).getText().equals("B")}? ID
 ;

ID : LETTER+;
WS : (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};

fragment LETTER: 'A'..'Z' ;
```

which would parse the input `B:B B B:C` into the following parse tree:

[image]

<sup>1</sup> [What is a 'semantic predicate' in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
grammar PrefixProblem;


options       
{   
language = Java;
}

 goal: (size_prefix ':')? (id|B);

size_prefix: B;

id: LETTER+;

LETTER: 'A'|'C'..'Z' ;

B: 'B';

WSFULL:(' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

Comment: Actually, it has the same con as PrefixSolution1, it requires striping the lexer, which i want to avoid

Comment: Oh yes, sorry i just realized that I came to the same solution as 2nd one. I will try to do something now