# ANTR3 set the number of accepted characters for a token

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3

I have to create a Lexer which will accept for example an integer only if it has a maximum of 8 digits. Is here an alternative to do it rather than just writing it like this?

```
INTEGER : (DIG | DIG DIG | DIG DIG DIG | ...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a *Gated Semantic Predicates* like this:

```
INTEGER
@init{int n = 1;}
  :  ({n <= 8}?=> DIGIT {n++;})+
  ;

fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
```

Details about this kind of predicate, see: [What is a 'semantic predicate' in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr)