# Forcing an alternative in ANTLR lexer rule

Tags: antlr, antlr3, lexer

I'm trying to code a context-sensitive lexer rule using ANTLR but can't get it to do what I need. The rule needs to match 1 of 2 alternatives based on characters found in the beginning of the rule. Below is greatly simplified version of the problem.

This example grammar:

```
lexer grammar X;

options
{
  language = C;
}

RULE :
  SimpleIdent {ctx->someFunction($SimpleIdent);}
  (
    {ctx->test != true}?
     //Nothing
  | {ctx->test == true}?
     SLSpace+ OtherText
  )
  ;

fragment SimpleIdent  : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_')+;
fragment SLSpace    : ' ';
fragment OtherText :  (~'\n')* '\n';
```

I would expect the lexer to exit this rule if *ctx->test* is false, ignoring any characters after SimpleIdent. Unfortunately ANTLR will test the character after SimpleIdent *before* the predicate is tested and thus will always take the second alternative if there is a space there. This is clearly shown in the C code:

```
// X.g:10:3: ({...}?|{...}? ( SLSpace )+ OtherText )
{
    int alt2=2;
    switch ( LA(1) )
    {
    case '\t':
    case ' ':
        {
            alt2=2;
        }
        break;

    default:
        alt2=1;
    }

    switch (alt2)
    {
    case 1:
        // X.g:11:5: {...}?
        {
            if ( !((ctx->test != true)) )
            {
                    //Exception
            }

        }
        break;
    case 2:
        // X.g:13:5: {...}? ( SLSpace )+ OtherText
        {
            if ( !((ctx->test == true)) )
            {
                   //Exception
            }
```

How can I force ANTLR to take a specific path in the lexer at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *gated semantic predicate* instead of a *validating semantic predicate* <sup>1</sup>. A *validating predicate* throws an exception if the expression validates to `false`. And let the *"Nothing alternative"* be the last to match.

Also, `OtherText` also matches what `SLSpace`, making `SLSpace+ OtherText` ambiguous. Simply remove `SLSpace+` from it, or let `OtherText` start with something other than a `' '`.

I'm not that familiar with the C target, but this Java demo should work just fine for C (after translating the Java code, of course):

```
grammar T;

rules
 : RULE+ EOF
 ;

RULE
 : SimpleIdent {boolean flag = $SimpleIdent.text.startsWith("a");}
   ( {!flag}?=> OtherText
   |            // Nothing
   )
 ;

Spaces 
 : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();}
 ;

fragment SimpleIdent : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_')+;
fragment OtherText   : (~'\n')* '\n';
```

If you'd now parse the input:

```
abcd efgh ijkl mnop
bbb aaa ccc ddd
```

you'll get the following parse:

[image]

I.e. whenever a `RULE` starts with a lower case `"a"`, it doesn't match all the way to the end of the line.

<sup>1</sup> [What is a 'semantic predicate' in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr)

Comment: This works for the simplified case in my question. Unfortunately in a more complex rule(one with DFA prediction functions), ANTLR converts the gated semantic predicate to a validating semantic predicate. I can't seem to force ANTLR to always take a path based on a condition determined at runtime.

Comment: @Adam12, in that case, consider providing a rule that is a better representation of your grammar.

Comment: I see what ANTLR is doing now. It hoists the predicates into the prediction function, but checks them again in the rule function.