# Syntax of semantic predicates in Antlr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

In [*What is a 'semantic predicate' in ANTLR3?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr3) Bart Kiers gives a very well overview about the different semantic predicates in Antlr3.

Too bad the syntax/semantics were seemingly changed in Antlr4, so this does not compile:

```
end_of_statement
    :   ';'
    |   EOF
    |   {input.LT(1).getType() == RBRACE}? =>
    ;

RBRACE
    : '}'
    ;
```

Could someone please tell me how to do the third case of *end_of_statement*: Accept if the next token is a '}' but do not consume it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is now just a single type of semantic predicates, which looks like this:

```
{ <<boolean-epxression>> }?
```

And the `input` attribute from the abstract class `Parser` (which your generated parser extends from) now has an underscore in front of it.

So, in your case, the following ANTLR v3 syntax:

```
{input.LT(1).getType() == RBRACE}? =>
```

would look like this in ANTLR v4:

```
{_input.LT(1).getType() == RBRACE}?
```