# Controlling token reduction

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlrworks, reduce-reduce-conflict

is there a way to controll the reduction operation of a token with ANTLR at runtime.
For example, I've an ANTLR grammar that looks like:

```
s: ( a | b);
a: WORD;
b: WORD;
WORD: ('a'..'z')+
```

Where the exact possible values related to both 'a' and 'b' are known at runtime, i.e. I want to decide at runtime whether to reduce a WORD to 'a' or 'b'.

Comment: Sorry, but this grammar wouldn't work. Can you explain more specifically, what really you want to achive? May be some example...

Comment: I know that there is a reduce-reduce conflit but I'm looking for a way to solve this conflit in runtime. I've a table of words that can be reduced to 'a' to 'b' but this time is filled at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a semantic predicate. Unless you plan on adding actions to rules a and b, this example won't be particularly useful.

```
s:
   {someBoolFunction();}? a
 | b
;
a: WORD;
b: WORD;
WORD: ('a'..'z')+
```

Comment: Hey, it is [Disambiguating Semantic Predicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr3) what I was looking for. thanks