# Antlr lexer support for range of occurrences?

Tags: antlr, lexer

Antlr's lexer supports Kleene closure (`*`) and positive Kleene closure (`+`) that indicates occurrences of a character for non-positive/positive times respectively. Is there a construct for Antlr's lexer to support a range of occurrences of a certain character like regular expressions do, like `'a' {8,16}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not. Not in ANTLR v3, nor in the future (now in beta) ANTLR v4.

You could use a predicate<sup>1</sup> to (manually) count the number of chars the rule has matched, and stop matching after a predefined number.

---

<sup>1</sup> [What is a 'semantic predicate' in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr3)