# ANTLR best way to include meta-data in lexing/parsing (custom objects, kind of annotation)

Tags: parsing, metadata, antlr3, lexical-analysis

I plan to include text metadata (like *bold*, *font-size*, etc.) in the process of parsing to achieve better recognition.

For instance, I have a given structure, where a word on its own line `word/r/n` which is *bold* and sized *24px*, is the title for some article. In order to get better recognition results, I want to take the characters as well as the metadata in account. In terms of ANTRL I'm not sure how this could be done best. I'd like to do something like:

1. Wrap each character of the original text into a custom object with fields for the metadata and pass that to ANTLR.
2. Preprocess the text and insert at specific places annotations for the metadata which is considered by the grammer.

I really like to take option **1.** but I'm not sure which part from ANTLR I need to subclass etc. Do I have to start at the `ANTLRInputStream-Object`, in order to get a proper stream for a subclassed *Lexer* to get custom *Tokens* for a subclassed *Parser* etc. Is there a more elegant way, especially in querying the tokens while parsing with actions in a `{}` block ?

If anyone has some hints and/or experiences this would be great!

EDIT:

Here is a more specific simple example: I have a file wich includes the encoding of metadata which I parse forehand. the actual text including *newline* look like the following:

```
entryOne
Here is some content one.
entryTwo
Here is some content two.
```

Where the titles`entryOne`and `entryTwo` are originally *font-size* of 24px and the content is *font-size* of 12px (as exemplary given values). Char by char I create a new instance of a custom object encapsulating the character as *String* and the *font-size*.

I initialize respective objects for each of the characters with fields of the font-size, e.g for the first letter of `entryOne` like
`MyChar aTitelChar = new MyChar("e", 24);`
For the content, like the second line `Here is some content one.` I create instances of MyChar like:

`MyChar aContentChar= new MyChar("H", 12);`

All characters of the texts are wrapped in instances of the below `MyChar`-*Class* and added to a `List<MyChar>` in order to produce a new input for ANTLR.

below is the Java Class for the characters:

```
public class MyChar {
    private int fontSizePx;
    private String text;

    public MyChar(String text, int fontSizePx) {
        this.text = text;
        this.fontSizePx = fontSizePx;
    }

    public int getFontSizePx() {
        return fontSizePx;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

I want that my grammar matches the above two entries (or more formatted this way) which in turn consist each of a title and a content which is terminated with a fullstop. This grammar could look like this:

```
rule: entry+ NEWLINE
;
entry:
title
content
;   
title: 
letters NEWLINE
;
content:
(letters)+ '.' NEWLINE
;
letters:
LETTERS 
;
LETTERS:
('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
;
WS:
(' ' | '\t' | 'f' ) + {$channel = HIDDEN;};
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n';
```

Now, for instance,  what I want to do is to find out if it's really a *title* of an entry by checking the *font-size* of all letters encompassing the *title-token* before `titel`-rule returns. In case the input conforms to the grammar but is actually some kind of mistake (the original metadata-encoded file starts with something that conforms to the `title`-rule but its actually the content) the author of the grammar could sort that out if he knows that the original *font-size* for titles is 24 and check this. If one of the letter-*tokens* doesn't equal to *font-size* 24 throw an exception/don't return/do smthg. appropriate.

The thing I'm pondering on is where to plug in the `List<MyChar>` to provide this functionality (to query kinds of metadata while parsing in context of ANTLR). I'm experimenting with ANTLR's Classes but as I'm new to ANTLR I thought probably some of the experienced users can point me in the right direction, like where would be a good insertion points for custom objects? should I start by implenting `CharStream` and override some methods? Probably there is something which ANTLR provides which I haven't found yet?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for, in relation to ANTLR specifically or lexing/parsing in general. I know that you have metadata somewhere (in the input?) and that you want it tied to (or closer to) the data.  But without more context -- more information about the grammar, more examples of input that the grammar represents -- I'm not sure that you'll get the kind of help that you want.

Comment: @tenterhook I see. I have edited my question, thanks. Bart Kiers thank you! I've overlooked the deletion button.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that helps. You mentioned that you want "to find out if it's really a title of an entry by checking the font-size of all letters encompassing the title-token before title-rule returns". Here's where I'm confused: the input to be parsed by ANTLR ("entryOne\nHere...entryTwo\nHere...") looks like plain-text, but you want to check the font-size of the input to know if something is really a title or not. Is the input actually plain-text? Is the meta-data for this input stored in the `List<MyChar>` variable that you mentioned?

Comment: thanks for the reply. `List<MyChar>` holds objects with a field for  plain text and one for _font-size_. The input-text example above is just for the grammar. I want to use the ANTLR_lexer_/_parser like I'd pass a String-Instance to the default `ANTLRStringStream(String input)` but something like `new MyANTLRStream(List<MyChar>input)`(`MyANTLRStream`extends`ANTLRStringStream') - but here I'm not sure if I'm thinking correctly. I just want to reference fields of MyChar instances in blocks in the grammar like the value of a rule but access the Mychar-Instances of the respective Token as well.

Comment: I think I'm following you. Instead of passing `List<MyChar>` in a custom `ANTLRStringStream`, it would be easier to pass it to the parser itself. Will there be one `MyChar` for every character of input that ANTLR reads?

Comment: Yes, I thought so. But as a wrote I'm not sure if it's the best way. If I'd pass it straight to the parser I need to take care that every Token knows the sublist of <MyChar> it consists of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish what I think you're going for, using the parser to manage matching input to metadata. Note that I made whitespace significant because it's part of the content and can't be skipped. I also made periods part of content to simplify the example, rather than using them as a marker.

**SysEx.g**

```
grammar SysEx;

@header {
    import java.util.List;
}

@parser::members {
        private List<MyChar> metadata;
        private int curpos;

        private boolean isTitleInput(String input) {
            return isFontSizeInput(input, 24);
        }

        private boolean isContentInput(String input){
            return isFontSizeInput(input, 12);
        }

        private boolean isFontSizeInput(String input, int fontSize){
            List<MyChar> sublist = metadata.subList(curpos, curpos + input.length());

            System.out.println(String.format("Testing metadata for input=\%s, font-size=\%d", input, fontSize));

            int start = curpos;            
            //move our metadata pointer forward.
            skipInput(input);

            for (int i = 0, count = input.length(); i < count; ++i){
                MyChar chardata = sublist.get(i);
                char c = input.charAt(i);
                if (chardata.getText().charAt(0) != c){
                    //This character doesn't match the metadata (ERROR!)
                    System.out.println(String.format("Content mismatch at metadata position \%d: metadata=(\%s,\%d); input=\%c", start + i, chardata.getText(), chardata.getFontSizePx(), c));
                    return false;
                } else if (chardata.getFontSizePx() != fontSize){
                    //The font is wrong.
                    System.out.println(String.format("Format mismatch at metadata position \%d: metadata=(\%s,\%d); input=\%c", start + i, chardata.getText(), chardata.getFontSizePx(), c));
                    return false;
                }
            }

            //All characters check out.
            return true;
        }

        private void skipInput(String str){
            curpos += str.length();
            System.out.println("\t\tMoving metadata pointer ahead by " + str.length() + " to " + curpos);
        }
}

rule[List<MyChar> metadata]
    @init {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }
    : entry+ EOF
    ;
entry
    : title content
    {System.out.println("Finished reading entry.");}
    ;   
title
    : line {isTitleInput($line.text)}? newline {System.out.println("Finished reading title " + $line.text);}
    ;
content
    : line {isContentInput($line.text)}? newline {System.out.println("Finished reading content " + $line.text);}
    ;
newline
    : (NEWLINE{skipInput($NEWLINE.text);})+
    ;
line returns [String text]
    @init { 
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    }
    @after {
        $text = builder.toString();
    }
    : (ANY{builder.append($ANY.text);})+ 
    ;

NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n';
ANY: .; //whitespace can't be skipped because it's content.
```

A `title` is a `line` that matches the title metadata (size 24 font) followed by one or more newline characters.

A `content` is a `line` that matches the content metadata (size 12 font) followed by one or more newline characters. As mentioned above, I removed the check for a period for simplification.

A `line` is a sequence of characters that does not include newline characters.

A [validating semantic predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3056517/1201210) (the `{...}?` after `line`) is used to validate that the line matches the metadata.

Here is the code I used to test the grammar (minus imports, for brevity):

**SysExGrammar.java**

```
public class SysExGrammar {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Create some metadata that matches our input.
        List<MyChar> matchingMetadata = new ArrayList<MyChar>();
        appendMetadata(matchingMetadata, "entryOne\r\n", 24);
        appendMetadata(matchingMetadata, "Here is some content one.\r\n", 12);
        appendMetadata(matchingMetadata, "entryTwo\r\n", 24);
        appendMetadata(matchingMetadata, "Here is some content two.\r\n", 12);

        parseInput(matchingMetadata);

        System.out.println("Finished example #1");


        //Create some metadata that doesn't match our input (negative test).
        List<MyChar> mismatchingMetadata = new ArrayList<MyChar>();
        appendMetadata(mismatchingMetadata, "entryOne\r\n", 24);
        appendMetadata(mismatchingMetadata, "Here is some content one.\r\n", 12);
        appendMetadata(mismatchingMetadata, "entryTwo\r\n", 12); //content font size!
        appendMetadata(mismatchingMetadata, "Here is some content two.\r\n", 12);

        parseInput(mismatchingMetadata);

        System.out.println("Finished example #2");
    }

    private static void parseInput(List<MyChar> metadata) throws Exception {
        //Test setup
        InputStream resource = SysExGrammar.class.getResourceAsStream("SysExTest.txt");

        CharStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(resource);

        resource.close();

        SysExLexer lexer = new SysExLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        SysExParser parser = new SysExParser(tokens);
        parser.rule(metadata);

        System.out.println("Parsing encountered " + parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() + " syntax errors");
    }

    private static void appendMetadata(List<MyChar> metadata, String string,
            int fontSize) {

        for (int i = 0, count = string.length(); i < count; ++i){
            metadata.add(new MyChar(string.charAt(i) + "", fontSize));
        }
    }
}
```

**SysExTest.txt** (note this uses Windows newlines (`\r\n`)

```
entryOne
Here is some content one.
entryTwo
Here is some content two.
```

**Test output** (trimmed; the second example has deliberately-mismatched metadata):

```
Parsing encountered 0 syntax errors
Finished example #1
Parsing encountered 2 syntax errors
Finished example #2
```

This solution requires that each `MyChar` corresponds to a character in the input (including newline characters, although you can remove that limitation if you like -- I would remove it if I didn't already have this answer written up ;) ).

As you can see, it's possible to tie the metadata to the parser and everything works as expected. I hope this helps.

Comment: total awesomeness! Very inspiring the usage of `@parser::members {..}` and the way you keep the `<MyChar>` in sync without subclassing anything! Too bad right now its too late here (or I'm too tired) to play around with it (3 am). I'll comment later on. Again, thank you!

Comment: now I checked it and you were right to hand it to the _parser_. I overlooked that one can define _private members_ in the grammar and that one can set custom parameters for the _rules_. I thought I have to rewrite a lot of types to make ANTLR except my custom objects. Another advantage is, that I'm not in danger to edit something which is generated - so this is very cool! Thanks again for writing a lot of lines for the implementation example and clear explanations - this is a good starting point for further experiments :)