# Semantic predicates in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

How would you translate this portion of code written in ANTLR 3 into ANTLR 4?

```
expr: (Identifier '.')=> (refIdentifier)
  | (Identifier '!')=> (refIdentifier)
  | (Identifier '=>')=> (lambdaExpression);
```

I mean this kind of semantic predicate does not seem to exist now. What could I use Instead?

Comment: In ANTLR terminology, these are syntactic predicates, not semantic predicates.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In ANTLR v4, there are no longer *gated semantic predicates*, `{ ... }?=>`, and there are also no longer *syntactic predicates*, `( ... )=>`, because the parsing algorithm used in v4 can resolve the ambiguities (the need for such predicates are no longer needed). So, this should just work for you:

```
expr
 : refIdentifier
 | refIdentifier
 | lambdaExpression
 ;
```

Note that there is just one type of predicate in v4: *semantic predicates*, `{ ... }?`. If you need to inspect the contents of a token, for example, you can do it like this:

```
id_capitals_only
 : {_input.LT(1).getText().matches("[A-Z]+")}? ID
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z]+
 ;
```

### EDIT

And as  Sam Harwell mentions in the comments:

> The semantic predicates {...}? in V4 work like the gated semantic predicates did in V3. The ungated predicates from V3 do not have a counterpart in ANTLR 4.

Comment: The semantic predicates `{...}?` in V4 work like the gated semantic predicates did in V3. The ungated predicates from V3 do not have a counterpart in ANTLR 4.