# Handle strings starting with whitespaces

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to create an ANTLR v4 grammar with the following set of rules:

1.In case a line starts with @, it is considered a label:

```
@label
```

2.In case the line starts with cmd, it is treated as a command

```
cmd param1 param2
```

3.If a line starts with a whitespace, it is considered a string. All the text should be extracted. Strings can be multiline, so they end with an empty line

```
 A long string with multiline support
 and any special characters one can imagine.
<-empty line here->
```

4.Lastly, in case a line starts with anything but whitespace, `@` and `cmd`, it's first word should be considered a heading.

```
Heading A long string with multiline support
 and any special characters one can imagine.
<-empty line here->
```

It was easy to handle lables and commands. But I am clueless about strings and headings.
What is the best way to separate `whitespace word whitespace whatever doubleNewline` and `whatever doubleNewline`? I've seen a lot of samples with whitespaces, but none of them works with both random text and newlines. I don't expect you to write actual code for me. Suggesting an approach will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
lexer grammar DemoLexer;

LABEL
 : '@' [a-zA-Z]+
 ;

CMD
 : 'cmd' ~[\r\n]+
 ;

STRING
 : ' ' .*? NL NL
 ;

HEADING
 : ( ~[@ \t\r\nc] | 'c' ~'m' | 'cm' ~'d' ).*? NL NL
 ;

SPACE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;

OTHER
 : .
 ;

fragment NL
 : '\r'? '\n'
 | '\r'
 ;
```

This does not mandate the "beginning of the line" requirement. If that is something you want, you'll have to add semantic predicates to your grammar, which ties it to a target language. For Java, that would look like this:

```
LABEL
 : {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? '@' [a-zA-Z]+
 ;
```

See:

- [Semantic predicates in ANTLR4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661754/semantic-predicates-in-antlr4)
- https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md