# ANTLR doesn't find the defined start rule

Tags: parsing, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm facing a strange ANTLR issue with a  that should just output an AST.

```
       grammar ltxt.g;

options
{
    language=CSharp3;
}


prog    : start
    ;

start       :   '{Start 'loopname'}'statement'{Ende 'loopname'}'
        |   statement
        ;

loopname    :   (('a'..'z')|('A'..'Z')|('1'..'9'))*;
statement   :   '<%' table_ref '>'
        |   start;

table_ref   :   '{'format'}'ID;

format      :   FSTRING 
        |   FSTRING OFSTRING{0,5}
        ;
FSTRING :   '#F'
    |   '#D'
    |   '#U'
    |   '#K'
    ;

OFSTRING:   'F'
    |   'D'
    |   'U'
    |   'K'
    //| 1..65536
    ;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;


WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

When I try to code-gen  this  I get

- error(100):LTXT.g:1:13:syntax error: antlr: MismatchedTokenException(74!=52). I didn't declare any 74 or 52.
- also I do not get a Synatx diagram, since "rule "start"" cannot be found as a start state...

I know that this  isn't pretty, but I thought it would work at least :)

Best,
wishi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four errors that I see.

- A grammar name can't contain a period. That's the syntax error you're getting. The `74!=52` error message is a hint telling you that ANTLR found token id 74 when it was expecting token id 52, which in this case just translates to "it found one thing when it expected something else."
- The grammar name ("ltxt") and the file name before the extension ("LTXT") need to match exactly.
- The grammar won't produce an AST unless you specify `output=AST;` in the `options` section.
- `format`'s second alternative (`FSTRING OFSTRING{0,5}`) won't do what I think you think it's going to do. ANTLR doesn't support an arbitrary number of matches such as "match zero to five `OFSTRING`s". You'll need to redefine the rule using [semantic predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3056517/1201210) that count occurrences for you. They aren't hard to use, but they're one of the trickier parts of ANTLR.

I hope that helps get you started.