# How can I limit the length of a token in antlr3?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr3

I am trying to build a compiler using antlr and for now I want to limit the length of the identifiers in my language to less than 9.

My code now look like this:

```
IDENTIFIER: CHAR(CHAR|INT)*;
```

where `CHAR` and `INT` are both fragments. I am wondering if there is any convenient way for me to achieve my goal instead of using this:

```
IDENTIFIER: CHAR(CHAR|INT)(CHAR|INT)...(CHAR|INT);//repeate (CHAR|INT) 8 times.
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr3) question. There is an example on Semantic Predicates that has an example that's similar to what you're asking.

Comment: @nvlass thanks I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You should to implement this using a separate check after the lexer is complete. If you attempt to validate the length of your identifier inside the lexer, then input containing `Identifier2Long` will likely do the following:

1. Fail to parse `Identifier` and recover by discarding the `I`.
2. Fail to parse `dentifier2` and recover by discarding the `d`.
3. ...more of this
4. Finally, successfully parse `fier2Long` as an identifier *and return that as the next token*.

You could implement the check by overriding [`Lexer.nextToken`](http://antlr3.org/api/Java/org/antlr/runtime/Lexer.html#nextToken%28%29).