# Resolving ANTLR ambiguity while matching specific Types

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer, ambiguous

I'm starting exploring ANTLR and I'm trying to match this format: (test123 A0020 )

Where :

- test123 is an Identifier of max 10 characters ( letters and digits )
- A : Time indicator ( for Am or Pm ), one letter can be either "A" or "P"
- 0020 : 4 digit format representing the time.

I tried this grammar :

```
    IDENTIFIER
:
    ( LETTER | DIGIT ) +
;
    INT
:
    DIGIT+
;
fragment
DIGIT
:
    [0-9]
;

fragment
LETTER
:
    [A-Z]
;

WS : [ \t\r\n(\s)+]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
formatter:  '(' information ')';

information : 
information '/' 'A' INT 
        |IDENTIFIER ;
```

How can I resolve the ambiguity and get the time format matched as 'A' INT not as IDENTIFIER?
Also how can I add checks like length of token to the identifier? 
I tknow that this doesn't work in ANTLR : IDENTIFIER : (DIGIT | LETTER ) {2,10}

**UPDATE:**

I changed the rules to have semantic checks but I still have the same ambiguity between the identifier and the Time format. here's the modified rules:

```
formatter
    : information
    | information '-' time
    ;

time :
    timeMode timeCode;  

timeMode:   
    { getCurrentToken().getText().matches("[A,C]")}? MOD
;

timeCode: {getCurrentToken().getText().matches("[0-9]{4}")}?  INT;

information: {getCurrentToken().getText().length() <= 10 }? IDENTIFIER;

MOD:  'A' | 'C';
```

So the problem is illustrated in the production tree, A0023 is  matched to timeMode and the parser is complaining that the timeCode is missing 
[image]

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr). Although you would have to convert your lexer rules to parser rules. The naive way is to write `IDENTIFIER: (LETTER | DIGIT) (LETTER | DIGIT) ...` ten times.

Comment: Why not tokenize `A0023` as a single TIME token?

Comment: @BartKiers because I want to include actions in the semantic rules later on without having to treat the 'A0023' as a String.( I will have to do operations if I want to separate the timeMode and timeCode ) I actually have the same problem in another parser for distance unit recognition ( format [M]\d{3} for distance in meter or [F]\d{4} in feets   )

Comment: I'm assuming the following inputs are all identifiers: `P123`, `P12345`, `P`. Correct?

Comment: Correct 1P23 12PP23, also are identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to handle it:

```
grammar Test;

@lexer::members {
  private boolean isAhead(int maxAmountOfCharacters, String pattern) {
    final Interval ahead = new Interval(this._tokenStartCharIndex, this._tokenStartCharIndex + maxAmountOfCharacters - 1);
    return this._input.getText(ahead).matches(pattern);
  }
}

parse
 : formatter EOF
 ;

formatter
 : information ( '-' time )?
 ;

time
 : timeMode timeCode
 ;

timeMode
 : TIME_MODE
 ;

timeCode
 : {getCurrentToken().getType() == IDENTIFIER_OR_INTEGER && getCurrentToken().getText().matches("\\d{4}")}?
   IDENTIFIER_OR_INTEGER
 ;

information
 : {getCurrentToken().getType() == IDENTIFIER_OR_INTEGER && getCurrentToken().getText().matches("\\w*[a-zA-Z]\\w*")}?
   IDENTIFIER_OR_INTEGER
 ;

IDENTIFIER_OR_INTEGER
 : {!isAhead(6, "[AP]\\d{4}(\\D|$)")}? [a-zA-Z0-9]+
 ;

TIME_MODE
 : [AP]
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;
```

A small test class:

```
public class Main {

    private static void indent(String lispTree) {

        int indentation = -1;

        for (final char c : lispTree.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == '(') {
                indentation++;
                for (int i = 0; i < indentation; i++) {
                    System.out.print(i == 0 ? "\n  " : "  ");
                }
            }
            else if (c == ')') {
                indentation--;
            }
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("1P23 - A0023"));
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        indent(parser.parse().toStringTree(parser));
    }
}
```

will print:

```
(parse 
  (formatter 
    (information 1P23) - 
    (time 
      (timeMode A) 
      (timeCode 0023))) <EOF>)
```

for the input `"1P23 - A0023"`.

### EDIT

ANTLR also can output the parse tree on UI component. If you do this instead:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("1P23 - A0023"));
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        new TreeViewer(Arrays.asList(TestParser.ruleNames), parser.parse()).open();
    }
}
```

the following dialog will appear:

[image]

Tested with ANTLR version 4.5.2-1

Comment: Awesome thanks, 
I tried it and it's working. ps: for some reason the parse tree generated with ANTLR eclipse plugin shows a different production ( timeMode missing and timeCode has A0023)

Comment: @JCCNoobie I tested with the latest ANTLR version 4.5.2-1

Comment: @JCCNoobie also see my EDIT.

Comment: This is so helpful thanks! The Parse Tree view from the ANTLR4 eclipse plugin doesn't show the same production so I will just use the TreeViewer instead. Thanks!

Comment: I have a problem with the small test class. every time i run it with the parser I get just this string (parse<EOF> ) even though i'm passing a full string to parse and it's beeing processed by the parser. Any idea what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Using semantic predicates (check this [amazing QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr)), you can define parser rules for your specific model, having logic checks that the information can be parsed. Note this is only an option for parser rules, not lexer rules.

```
information
    : information '/' meridien time
    | text
    ;
meridien
    : am
    | pm
    ;
am: {input.LT(1).getText() == "A"}? IDENTIFIER;
pm: {input.LT(1).getText() == "P"}? IDENTIFIER;
time: {input.LT(1).getText().length == 4}? INT;
text: {input.LT(1).getText().length <= 10}? IDENTIFIER;
```

Comment: I don't have Antlr right now to test this, so this may be off a little. Also, I'm using Java in the predicates, you may have to adjust to your host language if it's not Java.

Comment: Thanks,  so if I understand correctly, if I only want to have a lexer for my grammar I can't have specific checking rules for length. And if I need to apply a regex check It also has to be in the semantic predicates.

Comment: @JCCNoobie You can do it in the lexer, it's just not as elegant. For example, you may just repeat yourself, like `R: [A-Z] | [A-Z] [A-Z] | [A-Z] [A-Z] [A-Z];` for up to three letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
compileUnit
    :   alfaNum time
    ;

alfaNum : (ALFA | MOD | NUM)+;
time : MOD NUM+;

MOD:  'A' | 'P';
ALFA: [a-zA-Z];
NUM:  [0-9];

WS
    :   ' ' -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

You need to avoid ambiguity by including MOD into alfaNum rule.

Comment: Note "A" is an ambiguous lexicom, it could be either `MOD` or `ALFA`, and the lexer doesn't have the context to decide which one.

Comment: it has, because alfaNum has MOD included. it is alright this way, i have tested and used it before

Comment: I tried this solution, it resolves the ambiguity since it matches each character. the problem with this that if I have a list of Information strings (like TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 A0020) they will be matched as a same long alfaNum ( so I can't for example do this treatment: for each information store name )  http://s18.postimg.org/71vfzbepl/production.png

Comment: I have to admit that i have focused only on the core problem, but i do not understand now, how is it possible that three words will match. alfaNum rule wont match space and compileUnit (very bad name :D ) wont match more than two words

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you are right. I have to get back to this problem. Meanwhile define you can insert WS between alfaNum and time. Remove channel Hidden of course. I will find out the solution and let you know.