# How to use hyphen '-' in variable names with Xtext

Tags: tokenize, xtext

I need to write a XText grammar for a language that supports the hyphen '-' in variable names.

I tried with the toy example below where I define ID to be the pattern for variable names. What I am trying to specify here is that ID starts with a letter eventually followed by zero or more characters that are letters or '-' and ends with a letter (not an hyphen).

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl hidden(WS)

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    lines+=Line*
;
    
Line:
    (Variable | Expression) '.'
;

Variable:
    name=ID
;

Expression:
    '=' Atomic ({LinkedExpression.leftOperand=current} op=('->') rightOperand=Atomic)*
;

Atomic returns Expression:
    ref=[Variable]
;

terminal ID: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')(('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'-')*('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'))?;
terminal INT: ('0'..'9')+;
terminal WS: (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+;
```

The result is that if I try to parse the below text:

---

x.
y.
m-n.
**=x->y.**
=x -> y.
=m-n -> y.
**=m-n->y.**

---

The lines in bold fail as '-' in the '->' operator is read as part of a variable name; so for example:

=x->y.

is tokenised as:

```
=   x-   >   y   .
```

instead of:

```
=   x   ->   y   .
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you wrote would work in Antlr4, but XText is stuck in Antlr3. To do this in Antlr3, you'd write a [gated semantic predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr/3056517#3056517), e.g., `ID: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ( ( { input.LA(1) == '-' && input.LA(2) != '>'}? => ('-' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')) ) | ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9') )* ;` which I tested. I don't know whether XText allows this syntax, but it's worth a try.

Comment: It seems, form a quick google lookup, that this could be done only by changing the generated .g file manually...or writing some kind of plugin to do that. I am afraid I am not an enough sophisticated user to do that. Maybe it is possible by using parser rules to define ID instead of lexer rules?

Comment: Right. XText doesn't support gated semantic predicates. But, the rule can be written as a syntactic predicate, which XText does support. In Antlr3, the rule would be `ID: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ( ( ('-' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')) => ('-' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')) ) | ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9') )* ;`, and that works. I assume the rule in XText would be `terminal ID: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ( ( => ('-' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')) ) | ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9') )* ;`, but I can't check it at the moment because I don't have Eclipse/XText set up--whacked machine with Win11 OS upgrade.

Comment: maybe you should use datatype rules for both the -> and the - in Identifiers

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I used a parser rule to define IDs. This make things a bit trickier as you now need semantic predicates to give the new Id rule precedence over operators such as -> and the newly introduced minus operator ('-'). In addition I use hidden() when defining Id to make sure NO spaces are allowed in variable names.

The resulting grammar is pasted below; if somebody has a better or shorter grammar that does the same, please let me know. This looks a bit overcomplicated to me, but works as expected.

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl hidden(WS)

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
 

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    lines+=Line*
;

Id hidden():
    LETTERS+ (->'-' (LETTERS|NUMBERS)+)*
;   

Line:
    (Variable | Expression) '.'
;

Variable:
    name=Id
;

Expression:
    '=' AdditionExpression
;

AdditionExpression returns Expression:
    LinkedExpression ({AdditionExpression.leftOperand=current} op=('+'|'-') rightOperand=LinkedExpression)*
;

LinkedExpression returns Expression:
    Atomic ->({LinkedExpression.leftOperand=current} op=(ARROW_OPERATOR) rightOperand=LinkedExpression)*
;

Atomic returns Expression:
    ref=[Variable|Id]
;

terminal ARROW_OPERATOR: '->';
terminal LETTERS: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');
terminal NUMBERS: ('0'..'9')+;
terminal WS: (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+;
```

Please notice now:

```
x.
y.
m-n.
 
=m-n-x->x-y-m-n.
```

correctly causes a parse error as it is read as:

```
= (m-n-x) -> (x-y-m-n)
```

and no variable named "m-n-x" or "x-y-m-n" exists. While:

```
=m-n -x->x - y- m-n.
```

is interpreted correctly as:

```
= ( (m-n) - x ) -> (x - (y - (m-n))).
```

this of course forces the user to use spaces around the '-' operator (which I see no way to avoid).

Comment: did you look at datatype rules as proposed `ARROW_OPERATOR hidden(): '-''>';` `ID hidden():LETTERS+ (->'-' (LETTERS|NUMBERS)+)*; `

Comment: Hi @ChristianDietrich, your suggestion above generates a warning:
`warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/parser/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:424:3: Decision can match input such as "'-'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input`
Which means I still need the semantic predicate when I define LinkedExpression ...so it seems not to simplify the grammar.

Comment: you but it may solve the space problem