# Variable tokens in ANTLR grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, hl7, hl7-v2

I am attempting to create a ANTLR grammar for a HL7 derived language. HL7 has a feature that all the delimiters in a message are mapped using the first few bytes of the input itself. For example: `MSH|^~\&` specifies the various delimiters, in order of field separator `|` component separator `^`, repetition separator `~`, escape character `\`, subcomponent separator `&`.

Can an ANTLR grammar be produced that does not hardcode these tokens?

Comment: Antlr can handle this, but you will need to add predicates in the grammar for the parser or lexer to work with the dynamic nature of delimiters. I'm not sure how you want to structure the parser/lexer division of work, but I would choose either a "scannerless" style (in which their is just one rule in the lexer grammar `CHAR_ : .;`), or have a "smart" lexer that returns "field" tokens. The main issue with scannerless is that the parse trees would be huge, and you'd have to turn that off and insert a listener to do what you want during the parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted by Kaby76 in the comments: yes, it is possible with some [predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr) voodoo:

```
lexer grammar HL7Lexer;

@members {
  private char fieldSeparator;
  private char componentSeparator;
  private char repetitionSeparator;
  private char escapeSeparator;
  private char subcomponentSeparator;
  private boolean separatorsInitialised = false;

  private void setEncodingChars(String chars) {
    this.fieldSeparator = chars.charAt(3);
    this.componentSeparator = chars.charAt(4);
    this.repetitionSeparator = chars.charAt(5);
    this.escapeSeparator = chars.charAt(6);
    this.subcomponentSeparator = chars.charAt(7);
    this.separatorsInitialised = true;
  }

  private boolean isEncodingCharAhead() {
    if (!this.separatorsInitialised) {
      return true;
    }

    char ch = (char)this._input.LA(1);

    return ch == this.fieldSeparator || ch == this.componentSeparator
      || ch == this.repetitionSeparator || ch == this.escapeSeparator
      || ch == this.subcomponentSeparator;
  }
}

MSH
 : 'MSH' . . . . . {this.setEncodingChars(getText());}
 ;

FIELD_SEP
 : {this._input.LA(1) == this.fieldSeparator}? .
 ;

COMPONENT_SEP
 : {this._input.LA(1) == this.componentSeparator}? .
 ;

REPETITION_SEP
 : {this._input.LA(1) == this.repetitionSeparator}? .
 ;

ESCAPE_SEP
 : {this._input.LA(1) == this.escapeSeparator}? .
 ;

SUBCOMPONENT_SEP
 : {this._input.LA(1) == this.subcomponentSeparator}? .
 ;

OTHER
 : ( {!this.isEncodingCharAhead()}? . )+
 ;
```

When testing this lexer grammar with the input `MSH|^~\&|ADT1|GOOD HEALTH HOSPITAL|GHH LAB, INC.|GOOD HEALTH HOSPITAL|198808181126|SECURITY|ADT^A01^ADT_A01|MSG00001|P|2.8||`:

```java
String message = "MSH|^~\\&|ADT1|GOOD HEALTH HOSPITAL|GHH LAB, INC.|GOOD HEALTH HOSPITAL|198808181126|SECURITY|ADT^A01^ADT_A01|MSG00001|P|2.8||";
HL7Lexer lexer = new HL7Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(message));

CommonTokenStream stream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

stream.fill();

for (Token t : stream.getTokens()) {
    System.out.printf("%-20s '%s'\n",
        HL7Lexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()),
        t.getText().replace("\n", "\\n"));
}
```

the following tokens are created:

```
MSH                  'MSH|^~\&'
FIELD_SEP            '|'
OTHER                'ADT1'
FIELD_SEP            '|'
OTHER                'GOOD HEALTH HOSPITAL'
FIELD_SEP            '|'
OTHER                'GHH LAB, INC.'
FIELD_SEP            '|'
OTHER                'GOOD HEALTH HOSPITAL'
FIELD_SEP            '|'
OTHER                '198808181126'
FIELD_SEP            '|'
OTHER                'SECURITY'
FIELD_SEP            '|'
OTHER                'ADT'
COMPONENT_SEP        '^'
OTHER                'A01'
COMPONENT_SEP        '^'
OTHER                'ADT_A01'
FIELD_SEP            '|'
OTHER                'MSG00001'
FIELD_SEP            '|'
OTHER                'P'
FIELD_SEP            '|'
OTHER                '2.8'
FIELD_SEP            '|'
FIELD_SEP            '|'
EOF                  '<EOF>'
```